# INNER JOIN con varias tablas y filtros

Tags: mysql, sql, inner

Estoy acostumbrado en mysql a realizar consultas con subconsultas pero para este caso necesito hacerlo mediante JOINS y me esta costando bastante.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo estas tablas ¿Cómo podría sacar el nombre de las mujeres apuntadas en la clase con idClass = 100 impartidas por el profesor con idTeacher = 114?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera mas sencilla de entender las cosas es de manera grafica, y aquí te expongo un diseño de los datos que indicas, como puedes ver las tablas que contienen la información son las tablas: Student, Teacher  y Class, las tablas StudentClass y TeacherClass son parte de las relaciones ternarias, entre las tablas principales y la tabla Class, para el caso de este ejemplo se puede llegar a mostrar el contenido de Class por ambos lados, por la tabla Student o por Teacher, el colega te mostró la manera de llegar a travez de la tabla Teacher y esta correcto, las relaciones ternarias son entidades especialmente útiles cuando creamos un nuevo concepto en que 2 entidades participan para crear una nueva en este caso la tabla Class es la creación de alumnos en una clase que ademas esta compuesta por un profesor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta a través de Student quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT s.*,tC.idTeacher FROM StudentClass sC  
INNER JOIN TeacherClass tC ON (sC.idClass = tC.idClass)
INNER JOIN Student s ON (sC.idStudent = s.idStudent)
WHERE s.Gender = 'F' AND tC.idTeacher = 114 AND sC.idClass =100 ;
```

Comment: Al estar aceptada la respuesta, supongo que la consulta funciona, la idea es tener las condiciones de relación de las tablas como parte de la cláusula `on` del `join`, y las condiciones de filtrado de la consulta en la cláusula `where`. Mezclarlas solo hace que sea más difícil de leer la consulta.  Por otro lado, dudo que funcione, veo que falta la relación entre `class` y `TeacherClass` para poder filtrar correctamente.

Comment: @jachguate no lo habría publicado si no lo hubiese probado antes, para que no tengas que darte el trabajo de recrear la base para comprobarlo, te comparto un link donde la puedes descargar para que pruebes la consulta, saludos.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/pes18nkyu62d3g3/Dump20210616.sql?dl=0

Comment: Roberto, pronostico dos cosas con tu consulta: 1. Que lista todas las mujeres de la clase 100, las imparta el `idTeacher` 114 o no (puedes probarlo cambiando el `idTeacher` de la clase 100 a otro que no sea el 114, e igual va a listar a las mujeres que reciben esa clase. 2. Que si el idTeacher 114 imparte más de un curso, las mujeres de la clase 100 se van a duplicar, triplicar, cuadruplicar, etc. (Aparecerán tantas veces como cursos imparta el idTeacher 114.

Comment: @jachguate ,Tenias razón en el segundo punto, en el primero no daba el problema por la condición adicional en el INNER JOIN, en el segundo  punto si, ingrese otra materia al mismo profesor y claro se duplicaban, ya corregí el problema, saludos.

Comment: No estaría de más notificarle al AP, que seguro está interesado en ver la respuesta actualizada. Un saludo.

Comment: @DjEmilio84 , Estimado he modificado mi respuesta al cual contenía un error en la lógica, favor revisar, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente como ejercicio para usar todas las tablas:

```
SELECT Student.name
     FROM Student
     JOIN StudentClass using (idStudent)
     JOIN Class using (idClass)
     JOIN TeacherClass using (idClass)
     JOIN Teacher using (idTeacher)
WHERE Teacher.idTeacher = 144
  AND Class.idClass = 100
  AND Student.Gender = 'F'
```

Hay relaciones redundantes en el modelo, de manera que puedes relacionar alumnos con profesores sin pasar por la clase, y tampoco se usa la información específica del profesor más que su ID, así que esto puede quedar:

```
SELECT Student.name
     FROM Student
     JOIN StudentClass using (idStudent)
     -- redundante JOIN Class using (idClass)
     JOIN TeacherClass using (idClass)
     -- no se usa: JOIN Teacher using (idTeacher)
WHERE TeacherClass.idTeacher = 144
  AND Class.idClass = 100
  AND Student.Gender = 'F'
```

Comment: ¿podria usar AND studentclass.IdClass =  100?

Comment: @DjEmilio84 Podrías usarlo, el efecto es el mismo que la condición `Class.idClass = 100`. A mi me parece más natural hacer el filtro sobre la tabla `Class`, pero el resultado es el mismo, ya que por el join, en ambas tablas tienen que valer lo mismo.

Answer (score -1):

Sin las tablas no me es posible probar pero debería servir:

```
SELECT c.name FROM teacherclass a 
INNER JOIN studentclass b ON a.idclass = b.idclass 
INNER JOIN student c ON b.idstudent = c.idstudent 
WHERE a.idteacher = 114 AND a.idclass = 100 AND c.Gender='F';
```

Como consejo, comienza de lo general a lo particular, es decir:

Sabes que requieres el nombre, pero qué variables tienes para obtenerlo? En este caso el id de la clase y id de profesor, por lo que puedes arrancar de ese punto y continuar asociando las llaves primarias con los valores más particulares, como el caso de un nombre.

Comment: mujeres, no funciona tu solucion porque no filtras por sexo

Comment: Igual castigarlo con un -1 no creo que sea para tanto, tan solo por no haber agregado AND c.Gender='F' , la idea es lo que importa, tampoco se trata de insultar la inteligencia de quien pregunta.

Comment: Cierto, se me pasó agregarlo, recién comienzo a tratar de apoyar a los colegas con la poca experiencia que tengo ¿lo de insultar la inteligencia es por el -1 o por mi respuesta? Por otro lado no sé que tan malo sea un -1, sin embargo la idea es clara y agregar la condición era lo de menos, se agradece la retro pero no se acepta la calificación

Comment: Me refiero a insultar la inteligencia de la persona que pregunta, seguramente esa persona entenderá la idea sin problemas, y ella misma agregará la condición final. y lo decía por quien te puso -1, no refiriéndome a ti, saludos.

Comment: @Javier, sugiero que edites tu respuesta y agregues la condición. Deja un comentario a quien hizo el primer comentario y eso le dará la oportunidad de retirar el voto negativo (si fue ese usuario quien lo hizo, eso no se puede saber). Por otro lado, aunque la respuesta está aceptable sin esa condición, creo que estamos de acuerdo en que hace falta para cumplir lo solicitado en la pregunta, a cualquiera se nos pudo pasar por alto y lo bueno es que esos errores se pueden corregir con edición.